# Using regexes in PowerShell to remove text from a string

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I need to replace (remove) multiple possibilities of text in a string and I'm trying to do it all in one line (instead of having a bunch of if this do that stuff).  For example, I have a number of users with job titles, all at different levels (`Manager 1`, `Manager 2`, etc.).  Some of them end with numbers but some of them end with `II`, `III`, `IV`, etc. (roman numerals).  I'm using the following to remove the numbers (yes, in an array):

```
$_.CSVJobTitle = ((Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($objCSV."Job Title".ToLower())) -Replace " \d+$"
```

And that works great.  It removes the numbers from all of the Job Titles.  Because I am doing title case also, when the Job Title has `III`, I end up with Iii (using proper case).  But, when I try to add more to the above:

```
$_.CSVJobTitle = ((Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($objCSV."Job Title".ToLower())) -Replace " \d+$","ii$","iii$","iv$"
```

I get the following error message:

```
The -ireplace operator only permits 2 elements on the right-hand side, not 4
```

So I've been researching how to make this work and I keep reading about regex being the answer, and I'm sure that this is a simple answer, but I can't seem to understand how to make regex work in this situation.  I've read and tried so much on regexes and just can't get it and need help.  Is there some way to use the above command and remove (replace with nothing) the items that I am trying to remove?  Or is there a hard limit and I need to figure out something else?

Comment: @AlanMoore - I don't understand some of your edits.  Their identical to mine.  Some are now formatted as code (and I see the change for upper case characters) - thanks, but others there were no changes.  Oh well, appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a character class?

```
$_.CSVJobTitle = ((Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($objCSV."Job Title".ToLower())) -Replace '\s[0-9ivx]+$'
```

Or, with a some alternation thrown in:

```
-Replace '\s(?:\d+|[ivx]+)$'
```

Comment: An alternation seems a better choice to me here: `... -replace '(\d+|iii?|iv)$'`.

Comment: @mjolinor - Worked great (using the "some alteration" version), thank you.  (@AnsgarWiechers) - I tried it but using the "better choice" seemed to try and update all of the items in the array (I'm guessing that PS thinks it matches all items in the array?).

Comment: @mjolinor - I have learned more on regex thanks to this.  One thing that still gets me, what does the ?: represent - I can get the question mark but what does the : (colon) represent in regex?  I've looked at a few regex libraries and haven't seen a colon.

Comment: That makes it a non-capturing group. It more of a performance issue than an requirement for the regex to work. Without that, it will capture that group data, which isn't necessary since you're not going to do anything with it, so it tells regex not to bother with saving it.

Comment: I've come across some additional items (such as **Clerk III (12345)**), so I've updated the code to `-Replace '\s(?:\d+|[ivx]+|\(\d+\))'` but I also found that it is changing **IT Instructor** to **Itnstructor**.  Is it possible to adjust the RegEx further so that I don't have job titles like "Itnstructor"?  I haven't figured this one out yet.  Should I just add another (separate) replace line of code to replace **Itnstructor** after the RegEx completes?

Comment: Try this: '\s(?:\d+|[ivx]+)(?:\s*\(\d+\))?$' That adds the (12345) pattern as an optional match, and adds back the $ anchor that requires it to match at the end of the line (removing that is what's causing it to modify "IT Instructor").